# Xcode 7 GCDA corrupt arc tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-coverage

When I run unit test in Xcode 7, I'm getting below error.

```
cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag
```

In my run script I'm running below code in current and derived directory to remove all GCDA files

```
find . -name "*.gcda" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

In my post script code, I'm using **gcovr** to generate coverage report.

Some other forum mention on enabling below setting for main target, and disabling them for test target.

> Enable Code Coverage Support to YES
>   Generate Legacy Test Coverage Files to YES
>   Instrument Program Flow to YES

But this didn't work for me.